# How to sync two folders in different raspberry pi under same wifi

Tags: git, raspberry-pi

I have two pi zero w, 
I prepare to make one of them git-server. 
is there any way to sync my projects from pi git-server to another pi 
under the same wifi? 
I looked for some possible ways ex. own-cloud, 
people said own-cloud is not suit to lot of tiny files like codes.

Comment: I don't understand. You normally sync with a git server by using `git pull/push`, surely?

Comment: yes, Mr. Mark, 
I have two pi, and I hope I can make one be my git-server and another pi can backup my git-server

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of transferring files in Linux workspace is via **SCP**.

By running a simple command: scp /home/foo.txt pi@raspberrypi2:/home/foo.txt

If you wish to transfer a directory, the best option will be to use a -r argument, so the command will look something like this: scp /home/foo pi@raspberrypi2:/home/

Comment: thank you Mr. Nemanja, appreciate your answer, further question is, if I set crontab of SCP to my folder to another pi, could SCP detect the difference files from another pi, and just sync the difference part?

Comment: No, SCP is used for file transfer, not syncing files on multiple filesystems, you could use crontab to just copy the entire folder, either if you didn`t edited any files , they will just be copied!